# Interactive map designer

Tags: tilemap, python, level-design

I've made a simple game in pygame/pymunk. Currently my maps consists of lists with functions, e.g

```
ground_segments = [ground(position, size, shape...), ...]
```

I have equally built up lists for planks, stones, trees etc. And althoug it works, it is a bit tideous to work with.

I tried first tried making a tile-based map editor and `.txt` files to read/write to, but having a grid of letter felt limiting to wha I could add. Since I had a working concept of importing lists with the information I tried to build on that, but stopped once I realised I couldn't edit the contents of `map.py` from`level_editor.py`. Is there a workaround for that or do I need anothter concept? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [GameDev.se]! I have removed the link to google drive because of link rot issues. Please put everything needed for the question into the question text. If it helps, you can upload images/screenshots/animated gifs to stack's imgur service (guaranteed to not rot).

Comment: Have you considered to use a 3rd party map editor like [Tiled](https://www.mapeditor.org/)?

Comment: My bad, didn't know that but thanks for the info.

Comment: And no, I have not heard of it. Will look into it.